# How do you count the total number of hard links within a directory?

Tags: inode, hard-link

I've been trying to use the -ls and find commands to total the number of hard link occurrences within a directory.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this beyond physically counting all of the link counts >2 using the ls -li command?

Comment: Within the top level directory, or recursively?

Comment: Within the top level.

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. I'm seeking to count ALL occurrences of hard links, not the count of a single inode occurances.

Comment: So if a file in the current directory is hard-linked to a file in a parent or child directory, does it "count"?

Comment: Should `.` and `..` be counted  (on file  systems where they are implemented as hard links )?

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
(){echo $#} *(NDl+1)
```

Note that it doesn't count `.` nor `..`.

If you don't want to count directories (which on most file systems are always hard links), change to `*(NDl+1^/)`.

- `(){echo $#}` anonymous function which outputs its number of arguments
- `*(...)` glob with glob qualifiers
- `N`: enable `nullglob` for that glob (expand to nothing when there's no match)
- `D`: enable `dotglob` for that glob (includes hidden files, but never `.` nor `..`)
- `l+1`: select files with a number of links strictly greater than 1.
- `^/`: exclude files of type *directory*.

POSIX equivalent:

```
find .//. ! -name . -prune -links +1 | grep -c //
```

(add a `! -type d` after `-prune` to exclude directories).

Or with `ls`:

```
(export LC_ALL=C; ls -Aqn | awk 'NR > 1 && $2 > 1 {n++}; END {print n}')
```

To exclude directories, add `&& $1 !~ /^d/` after `$2 > 1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -qAi | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -d | wc -l
```

That counts inodes that are duplicated *in the current directory* (one of each, replace `-d` with `-D` to count all occurrences), so not counting hard links where all the other links live outside the current directory. `.` and `..` are excluded. Replace `-A` with `-a` to add them back (though it's very unlikely they would have hard links in the current directory anyway).

There may be a shorter way but this is very illustrative.

Mr. Pipe `|` is your friend.

(`man` too)

Have fun!

Comment: just want to point out that telling `ls` to `r`everse sort on `t`ime is pointless, given the later sorting. Also parsing `ls` is tricky; notice what happens if you `touch $'foo\nbar` and then pipe `ls ...|sort`

Comment: @JeffSchaller, my edit should address those concerns. Ronnie, please feel free to revert if you don't agree with the change.

Answer (score 1):

Given the Linux environment, you could use the `stat` command on each file and ask for the link count. You can decide if you want to include or exclude dot-files from the count with `shopt -s dotglob`.  In the loop below, I intentionally skip directories.

```
shopt -s dotglob
i=0
for f in ./*
do
  [ -d "$f" ] && continue
  if [ $(stat -c %h "$f") -gt 1 ]
  then
    i=$((i+1))
  fi
done
```

Alternatively, with GNU find:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 \! -type d -links +1 -printf . | wc -c
```

This asks `find` to look, starting in the current directory (`.`):

- *only* in the current directory (`-maxdepth 1`)
- skipping directories (`! -type d`, where the `!` is escaped from the shell)
- where the number of links is greater than 1
- in which case, print a period (`.`)
- ... and then count the number of periods emitted

Comment: Note that `[ -d "$f" ] && continue` also excludes symlinks to directories, while the `stat` call (which here assumes GNU `stat`) retrieves information on the symlink, not there target.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following one-liner to find the file with the highest hard links number:

```
find . -type f -exec ls -l {} \; | sort -nrk 2 | head -n 1
```

Hope this helps anyone else looking for the same.